# JavaFX 2 TitledPane graphics expansion to full size

Tags: resize, javafx-2, titlebar

I am trying to add a custom toolbar to a generic TitledPane.
My code seems to work (minimal example follows), but I have problems with layout.
Specifically: I am adding my toolbar using setGraphic(), but that seems to have a fixed width, while I would like it to expand so I can have the buttons flushed right while keeping title on the left side.

(I cannot post images, so I will revert to ASCII art)
This is the actual result of code below:

```
+------------------------------------+
| > Node 1 [a][b][c][d]              |
+------------------------------------+
| > Node                             |
+------------------------------------+
```

while I would like to get something like:

```
+------------------------------------+
| > Node 1              [a][b][c][d] |
+------------------------------------+
| > Node                             |
+------------------------------------+
```

I can fake the result setting explicitly the BorderPane width, but it will not follow resizing!

---

here starts the code:

```
import java.net.URL;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Accordion;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ContentDisplay;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

private Node loadMinitool(String title) {
    try {
        URL u = getClass().getResource("Minitool.fxml");
        FXMLLoader l = new FXMLLoader(u);
        Node n = (Node) l.load();
        Minitool mtc = (Minitool) l.getController();
        mtc.setTitle(title);
        return n;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to load 'Minitool.fxml': "+e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

public Parent createContent() {

    TitledPane t1 = new TitledPane(null, new Button("Button"));
    t1.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
    t1.setGraphic(loadMinitool("Node 1"));
    TitledPane t2 = new TitledPane("Node 2", new Text("String"));
    TitledPane t3 = new TitledPane("Node 3", new Rectangle(120, 50,
            Color.RED));

    Accordion accordion = new Accordion();

    accordion.getPanes().add(t1);
    accordion.getPanes().add(t2);
    accordion.getPanes().add(t3);

    accordion.setMinSize(100, 100);
    accordion.setPrefSize(200, 400);

    return accordion;

}

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(createContent()));
    primaryStage.show();

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

the associated FXML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.net.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<BorderPane maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" prefWidth="-1.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="com.voith.hyconmde.ui.util.minitool.Minitool">
  <left>
    <Label fx:id="title" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" text="Title goes here" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER_LEFT" />
  </left>
  <center>
    <Pane fx:id="filler" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="16.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
  </center>
  <right>
    <HBox>
      <Button fx:id="add" graphicTextGap="0.0" onAction="#addAction" styleClass="btnToolbar" />
      <Button fx:id="del" graphicTextGap="0.0" onAction="#delAction" styleClass="btnToolbar" />
      <Button fx:id="sub" graphicTextGap="0.0" onAction="#subAction" styleClass="btnToolbar" />
      <Button fx:id="dup" graphicTextGap="0.0" onAction="#dupAction" styleClass="btnToolbar" />
    </HBox>
  </right>
  <stylesheets>
    <URL value="@Minitool.css" />
  </stylesheets>
</BorderPane>
```

and the controller is:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;

public class Minitool {

    @FXML private ResourceBundle resources;
    @FXML private URL location;
    @FXML private Button add;
    @FXML private Button del;
    @FXML private Button dup;
    @FXML private Button sub;    
    @FXML private Label title;

    @FXML void addAction(ActionEvent event) {
    } 
    @FXML void delAction(ActionEvent event) {
    }
    @FXML void dupAction(ActionEvent event) {
    }
    @FXML void subAction(ActionEvent event) {
    }
    @FXML void initialize() {
        assert add != null : "fx:id=\"add\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Minitool.fxml'.";
        assert del != null : "fx:id=\"del\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Minitool.fxml'.";
        assert dup != null : "fx:id=\"dup\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Minitool.fxml'.";
        assert sub != null : "fx:id=\"sub\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Minitool.fxml'.";
        assert title != null : "fx:id=\"title\" was not injected: check your FXML file 'Minitool.fxml'.";
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title.setText(title);
    }

    public void setWidth() {
        if (parent == null) {
            Parent p = minitool.getParent();
                if (p != null)
            p = p.getParent();
            if (p instanceof TitledPane) {
                parent = (TitledPane) p;
                parent.widthProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Object>() {
                    @Override
                    public void changed(ObservableValue<?> observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                        if (newValue instanceof Number) {
                            Number n = (Number) newValue;
                            double d = n.doubleValue();
                            setFiller(d);
                        }
                    }
                });
                setFiller(parent.getWidth());
            }
        }
    }

    protected void setFiller(double d) {
        double w = d - title.getWidth() - 180; // XXX: this value has been hand-trimmed!
        if (w < 0)
            w = 0;
        filler.setPrefWidth(w);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added resize support, but it does not work well. Size increase is ok, but size decrease is not fluid and sometimes stops (mouse moves, size does not). Is this the only way to do this thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do some basic math. Follow modifications to your code below:
1) In fxml file add properties to HBox:

```
<HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
```

The result is, when there is an extra space in title width (by resizing), this HBox will have a priority to expand and its children will always be aligned to the right (center).

2) Now we need to calculate the remaining title width this way

```
REMAINING_WIDTH = TITLE_TOTAL_WIDTH - TITLE_TEXT_WIDTH - ARROW_BUTTON_WIDTH - RIGHT_LEFT_PADDINGS
```

The calculated width will be our tool buttons pane's (i.e. HBox's) preferred width.

```
public Parent createContent() {

        String titleText = "Node 1";

        TitledPane t1 = new TitledPane(null, new Button("Button"));
        t1.setContentDisplay(ContentDisplay.GRAPHIC_ONLY);
        t1.setGraphic(loadMinitool(titleText));

        double titleTextWidth = computeTextWidth(t1.getFont(), titleText, 0);
        double arrowButtonWidth = 14;  // I have given a static value here otherwise
            // it must be calculated by
            // t1.lookup(".arrow-button").getLayoutBounds().getWidth()
            // after the primary stage has been shown. Namely after primaryStage.show(); line.
        double paddings = 20; // right (10) and left (10) paddings defined in 
            // caspian.css for title of the pane. These values can also be obtained 
            // by lookup.
        double total = titleTextWidth + arrowButtonWidth + paddings;

        HBox toolButtons = (HBox) ((BorderPane) t1.getGraphic()).getRight();
        toolButtons.prefWidthProperty().bind(t1.widthProperty().subtract(total));

        TitledPane t2 = new TitledPane("Node 2", new Text("String"));
        TitledPane t3 = new TitledPane("Node 3", new Rectangle(120, 50,
                Color.RED));

        Accordion accordion = new Accordion();
        accordion.getPanes().add(t1);
        accordion.getPanes().add(t2);
        accordion.getPanes().add(t3);
        accordion.setMinSize(100, 100);
        accordion.setPrefSize(200, 400);

        return accordion;
    }
```

The `computeTextWidth()` code is taken from `com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.Utils`, and for reference only:

```
private double computeTextWidth(Font font, String text, double wrappingWidth) {
    Text helper = new Text();
    helper.setText(text);
    helper.setFont(font);
    // Note that the wrapping width needs to be set to zero before
    // getting the text's real preferred width.
    helper.setWrappingWidth(0);
    double w = Math.min(helper.prefWidth(-1), wrappingWidth);
    helper.setWrappingWidth((int) Math.ceil(w));
    return Math.ceil(helper.getLayoutBounds().getWidth());
}
```

The other codes of yours remain the same.

Comment: I came up with a solution similar to Yours, but taking into account resizing. It does not work very well and it is very sensitive to trim value. I updated my code.

Comment: @ZioByte. your updated code is incomplete. And your approach is not similar to mine. I suggest you to try my code literally. It uses bindings and the various text widths have been taken into account.

Answer (score 3):

I've come up with that solution:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TitledPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestApp extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        TitledPane title = new TitledPane();
        //title.setContent(new Label("Content"));

        Node graphic = new Button("Click");
        Label label = new Label("Titled Pane Header");
        // Allow the label to grow to max width
        label.setMaxWidth(Double.MAX_VALUE);
        // Let it actually grow
        HBox.setHgrow(label, Priority.ALWAYS);
        HBox hBox = new HBox(label, graphic);
        hBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_LEFT);
        hBox.setPadding(new Insets(0, 3, 0, 0));

        // Bind the HBox's min width to the TitledPane's width and subtract arrow (15) and left padding (10)
        hBox.minWidthProperty().bind(title.widthProperty().subtract(25));

        title.setGraphic(hBox);

        Scene scene = new Scene(new VBox(title), 300, 250);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a much simpler solution - just set the pref width of the graphic to Double.MAX_VALUE and this will take up the width of the titled pane - you may need to wrap the graphic in a BorderPane first. (Create BorderPane with graphic in centre and then set the pref width of that border pane)